# scrollview like in facebook application

Tags: android

I want to create a scrollview like at the "Facebook" application.
When you swipe right with your finger you get a list view with the following: "News Feed", "Messages" etc.
When you swipe left you see a view with all your friends you can chat with.
Someone know how it is called? so I will search it on web and implement it in my app?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13082640/menu-like-facebook-and-sliding-from-one-view-to-another-by-touch-in-android-2-2